# WPF Binding inner control with parent data context

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I made a user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"  x:Name="uc">
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.TextContent, ElementName=uc}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.TextContent2, ElementName=uc}"/>
</Grid>
```

I want the sub-controls in the defined control(uc) will bind to the properties of uc.DataContext. I used the defined control as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="Tms.TMSClient.Views.MainWindow" Name="window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary">      

    <control:MyControl DataContext="{Binding Path=MyControlVM}"/>
```

The DataContext which is assigned to the window has this structure: WindowVM.MyControlVM.TextContent.

The given code does not work because the textbox's DataContext is bound to WindowVM instead. I think the problem may be because the inner textbox is bound before the defined control (uc) is, thus the bounded DataContext for *uc* does not take effect yet.

What I want is: the custom control (MyControl) will be bound to its corresponding viewmodel (MyControlVM), and the inner elements of MyControl will be bound to the properties of MyControlVM.

Do you have any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, do something like `DataContext = this` in `MyApp.MyControl`? Also, if you don't change `DataContext` in control `{Binding TextContent}` should be enough

Comment: You set `MyControlVM.DataContext` to `MyControlVM`, and since it's inherited through visual tree, everything inside, by default and until you change it will have that `DataContext`. In your case `TextBlock`, `Grid` and `UserControl` will have same `DataContext` set from outside to `MyControlVM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextContent}"/>
```

works for me in my test-application.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DataContextTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:DataContextTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <my:MyOuterDataContext />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <my:MyControl DataContext="{Binding Path=MyInnerDataContext}" />
</Grid>
```

MyControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataContextTest.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextContent}" />
</Grid>
```

DataContexts:

```
public class MyOuterDataContext
{
    public MyInnerDataContext MyInnerDataContext { get; set; }

    public MyOuterDataContext()
    {
        MyInnerDataContext = new MyInnerDataContext();
    }
}

public class MyInnerDataContext
{
    public string TextContent { get { return "foo"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, you want to data bind a property from your `MyControl` view model to a `TextBox.Text` property inside the `MyControl UserControl`. If that is correct, then you can use a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx), or the `ElementName` syntax that you are already using.

First, make sure that your view model is set as the `DataContext` for the `UserControl`:

```
public MyControl()
{
    DataContext = new YourControlViewModel();
}
```

As child controls automatically inherit their parent's `DataContext` objects, you can now reference this view model from the `TextBox` through the `MyControl.DataContext` property from the `UserControl`'s XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.TextContent, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 4):

By default every control inherits its DataContext from its parent control. Thus there is no need to explicitly bind to it.

Indeed, when you want to bind a control's DataContext to a nested property then you have to specifiy this:

```
<control:MyControl DataContext="{Binding Path=TextContent}"/>
```

Comment: The defined control may have many inner elements, so binding directly as your suggestion is not good. What I want is: the custom control (MyControl) will be bound to its corresponding viewmodel (MyControlVM), and the inner elements of MyControl will be bound to the properties of MyControlVM

Comment: Wow @ThomasLee, you're really not listening to anyone here, are you? THE `DataContext` IS AUTOMATICALLY INHERITED BY ALL CHILD CONTROLS BY DEFAULT. I don't see any problem with your code as it stands, so you must have something else interfering with it.